# Set SameSite using Apache configuration not working

Tags: apache, google-chrome, browser, server, samesite

I search many way to **configuration** my server[**Apache**] for resolve **SameSite** after browser updates. I try to many time for edit in **.htaccess** and **httpd.conf** file but not works at all.

please help me to resolve this problem ^^

**.htaccess file**
[image]

**httpd.conf**
[image]

Comment: Confirm your apache httpd version.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I have apache httpd.x86_64  2.2.15-69.e16.contos.

Comment: Could you pelase remove `always` from Header and let me know result.

Comment: Are you think cuz of apache version right? or maybe this page is not https